# Different behavior between g++/clang when implementing a vector-like data structure

Tags: c++, c

I stumbled upon this idea to implement a vector/dynamic array kind of structure called *stretchy buffers*. This being a C technique, it is not well suited to modern C++ idioms but I wanted to entertain the idea because it seemed so compact and *beautiful* in some sense. So I modified it a little bit to make it compile with a modern C++ compiler. Since, as I said, it is really compact; I am going to share the whole code here.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

typedef struct buf_hdr {
    size_t len;
    size_t cap;
    uint8_t buf[1];
} buf_hdr;

#define buf_hdr_(b) ((buf_hdr*)((uint8_t *)b - offsetof(buf_hdr, buf)))
#define buf_len(b) ((b) ? buf_hdr_(b)->len : 0)
#define buf_cap(b) ((b) ? buf_hdr_(b)->cap : 0)
#define has_space_(b, n) (buf_len(b) + (n) <= buf_cap(b))

void* buf_grow_(void* b, size_t new_len, size_t elem_size) {
    size_t new_cap = MAX(1 + 2 * buf_cap(b), new_len);
    size_t new_byte_size = offsetof(buf_hdr, buf) + new_cap * elem_size;
    buf_hdr* new_hdr = NULL;
    if(b) {
        new_hdr = (buf_hdr*) realloc(buf_hdr_(b), new_byte_size);
    } else {
        new_hdr = (buf_hdr*) malloc(new_byte_size);
    }
    new_hdr->cap = new_cap;
    return new_hdr->buf;
}

#define buf_fit(b, n) (has_space_(b, n) ? 0 : (b) = (decltype(b))buf_grow_((b), buf_len(b) + (n), sizeof(*b)))
#define buf_push(b, e) (buf_fit(b, 1), (b)[buf_len(b)] = (e), buf_hdr_(b)->len++)
#define buf_free(b) ((b) ? free(buf_hdr_(b)) : (void)0)

int main() {
    int *buf = NULL;
    buf_push(buf, 42);
    buf_push(buf, 1234);
    buf_push(buf, 65536);
    printf("len = %lu \n", buf_hdr_(buf)->len);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < buf_len(buf); ++i) {
        printf("%d ", buf[i]);
    }
    buf_free(buf);

    float * fbuf = NULL;
    buf_push(fbuf, 3.14f);
    buf_push(fbuf, 2.71f);
    buf_push(fbuf, 1.65f);
    printf("len = %lu \n", buf_len(fbuf));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < buf_len(fbuf); ++i) {
        printf("%f ", fbuf[i]);
    }
    buf_free(fbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this on godbolt, GCC gives the expected output:

```
len = 3 
42 1234 65536 len = 3 
3.140000 2.710000 1.650000
```

But for some reason, Clang prints just:

```
len=0
len=0
```

I am wondering, what possible error in the macro expansion (or maybe something else but that's what I am suspecting right now) gives rise to this difference?

Update: Turns out, probably this is not about macros. On wandbox, I get segmentation fault on both compilers. I have no idea why clang and g++ are not giving segfaults on godbolt, but just different outputs. On top of that, g++ prints correct results on godbolt. There is some undefined behavior I am raising it seems, but I am sort of lost.

Comment: Use `valgrind` and AddressSanitizer and the undefined behavior becomes apparent. Hint: AddressSanitizer says "_address points to the zero page_" at `buf_push(buf, 42);`.

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you, this is not considered beautiful in C++. There are other idiomatic ways to do the exact same thing.